# Spring 4 Servlet and a configuration file

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring 4 MVC Servlet, which uses JPA and spring-orm to connect to the database. My `applicationContext.xml` file contains the following:

```
<util:map id="persistenceUnitConfiguration">
    <entry key="javax.persistence.logging.level" value="INFO" />
    <entry key="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <entry key="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/DATABASE" />
    <entry key="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="USERNAME" />
    <entry key="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="PASSWORD" />
    <entry key="eclipselink.weaving" value="false" />
</util:map>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
      id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPersistenceUnit" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaAdapter" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="my.package.entities" />
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap" ref="persistenceUnitConfiguration" />
</bean>
```

The application is packaged as a WAR. I want to somehow configure the DATABASE, USERNAME, and PASSWORD values, such that I can distribute the WAR and nobody has to touch it. Only thing to do would be to edit a configuration file somewhere.

What is the best approach for doing so?

Can I somehow set the jpaPropertyMap programmatically during boot of my webapp and read it from a configuration file at a fixed location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a properties file like database.properties:

```
db.user=youruser
db.password=yourpassword
```

Then in your Spring application config file, add

```xml
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:my/package/config/database.properties" />
```

Now you can access to the properties using expression language syntax:

```xml
<bean ...>
    <property name="dbUser" value="${db.user}" />
    <property name="dbPassword" value="${db.password}" />
</bean>
```

If you're using annotation config, then use

```
@Component
public class YourBean {
    @Value( "${db.user}" )
    private String dbUser;

    @Value( "${db.password}" )
    private String dbPassword;
}
```

Applied to your case, it would be (similar for more fields)

```xml
<util:map id="persistenceUnitConfiguration">
    <entry key="javax.persistence.logging.level" value="INFO" />
    <entry key="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <entry key="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/DATABASE" />
    <entry key="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="${db.user}" />
    <entry key="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="${db.password}" />
    <entry key="eclipselink.weaving" value="false" />
</util:map>
```

If your properties file is outside classpath, use `file:` instead:

```xml
<context:property-placeholder location="file:/path/to/your/database.properties" />
```

Comment: What if I wanted to specify a specific configuration file which is not on the classpath, say in `/etc/my/glorious/package.conf`?